# How to call method inside the fragment from activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm having problem with calling method inside of my fragment.

Method is called : `public static List<mobAppModel> getmobAppModel(Context ctx)`

My Activity where method is located:

```
package com.example.eronetmarket;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import com.example.eronetmarket.mobAppModel;


import android.content.Context;


public class XMLsourcePullParser {
    static final String KEY_APP_INFO = "appInfo";
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_CATEGORY = "category";
    static final String KEY_ICON_URL = "iconUrl";
    static final String KEY_APP_HEADLINE = "appHeadline";
    static final String KEY_APP_DESC = "appDesc";
    static final String KEY_RATING_POINTS = "ratingPoints";
    static final String KEY_PLATFORM = "platform";
    static final String KEY_STORE_URL = "storeUrl";
    static final String KEY_STORE_PRICE = "storePrice";
    static final String KEY_DEVELOPER = "developer";

    public static List<mobAppModel> getmobAppModel(Context ctx) {

        // List of StackSites that we will return
        List<mobAppModel> appModels;
        appModels = new ArrayList<mobAppModel>();

        // temp holder for current StackSite while parsing
        mobAppModel curmobAppModel = null;
        // temp holder for current text value while parsing
        String curText = "";

        try {
            // Get our factory and PullParser
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

            // Open up InputStream and Reader of our file.
            FileInputStream fis = ctx.openFileInput("XMLsource.xml");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

            // point the parser to our file.
            xpp.setInput(reader);

            // get initial eventType
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

            // Loop through pull events until we reach END_DOCUMENT
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                // Get the current tag
                String tagname = xpp.getName();

                // React to different event types appropriately
                switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_APP_INFO)) {
                        // If we are starting a new <site> block we need
                        //a new StackSite object to represent it
                        curmobAppModel = new mobAppModel();
                    }
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    //grab the current text so we can use it in END_TAG event
                    curText = xpp.getText();
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_APP_INFO)) {
                        // if </appInfo> then we are done with current app
                        // add it to the list.
                        appModels.add(curmobAppModel);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_ID)) {

                        curmobAppModel.setid(curText);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_CATEGORY)) {

                        curmobAppModel.setcategory(curText);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_ICON_URL)) {

                        curmobAppModel.seticonUrl(curText);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_APP_HEADLINE)) {

                        curmobAppModel.setappHeadline(curText);

                    }
                    else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_APP_DESC)) {

                        curmobAppModel.setappDesc(curText);

                    }
                    else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_RATING_POINTS)) {

                        curmobAppModel.setratingPoints(curText);

                    }
                    else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_PLATFORM)) {

                        curmobAppModel.setplatform(curText);

                    }
                    else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_STORE_URL)) {

                        curmobAppModel.setstoreURL(curText);
                    }
                    else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_STORE_PRICE)) {

                        curmobAppModel.setstorePrice(curText);
                    }
                    else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_DEVELOPER)) {

                        curmobAppModel.setdeveloper(curText);
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
                //move on to next iteration
                eventType = xpp.next();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // return the populated list.
        return appModels;
    }
}`
```

This is my fragment:

```
package com.example.eronetmarket;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Preporuceno extends Fragment   {



    private AppAdapter mAdapter;
    private ListView siteList;

    private LinearLayout ll;
    private FragmentActivity fa;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    fa = super.getActivity();
    ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_preporuceno, container, false);

        siteList = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        siteList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,long id) {
                String url = mAdapter.getItem(pos).getstoreURL();
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });



        if(isNetworkAvailable()){
            Log.i("mobAppModel", "starting download Task");
            AppDownloadTask download = new AppDownloadTask();
            download.execute();
        }else{
            mAdapter = new AppAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), -1, XMLsourcePullParser.getmobAppModel(Preporuceno.this));
            siteList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }

        return ll;}
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
              = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    } 
    private class AppDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            //Download the file
            try {
                Downloader.DownloadFromUrl("http://minores.info/joomla30/stacksites.xml", getActivity().openFileOutput("XMLsource.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
            //setup our Adapter and set it to the ListView.
            mAdapter = new AppAdapter(Preporuceno.this, -1, XMLsourcePullParser.getmobAppModel(Preporuceno.this));
            siteList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            Log.i("mobAppModel", "adapter size = "+ mAdapter.getCount());
        }
    }

    }
```

I get an error at

```
XMLsourcePullParser.getmobAppModel(Preporuceno.this)
```

that

```
The method getmobAppModel(Context) in the type XMLsourcePullParser is not applicable for the arguments (Preporuceno)
```

I'm totally confused :\
As a activity works fine, but as fragment this is the problem...

Comment: in a fragment, the `context` is usually `getActivity()`

Comment: Thats not actualy about calling a method from activity, but using correct argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fragment does not extends a Context, because his context is the activity is inside, so you should call getmobAppModel(getActivity()).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use some event bus, like [Otto](https://github.com/square/otto) from Square

Comment: Considering you also need to setup a singleton-handling IoC container to make this be seamless (like Dagger), it doesn't seem *that* simple, although luckily Dagger was designed to be fairly simple in its usage.

Comment: You can keep Otto instance on applicationContext. It simple enough. Dagger makes it too complex for begginer

Comment: in that case wouldn't you need to do `((MyApplication)(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).getEventBus()` each time? that seems nasty.

Comment: Just once to get the instace (Create some class you will inhrerit, that will register and unregister and get the instance). It is ugly, but easiest way to communicate between Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get your context from your Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);
    myContext=activity;
}
```

then use your method like this :

```
XMLsourcePullParser.getmobAppModel(myContext)
```

Comment: Activity is always awaylable (when attached) through the getActivity() method. No need to keep extra field for it.